# Getting the amount of users who reacted to a message with a certain emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I get the amount of users who reacted with emoji to a specific message

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(message.id).then(function(r){
    return console.log(r.reactions.filter(a => a.emoji.name == '')).users.size
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`<MessageReaction>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) has a [count](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=count) property which returns

> The number of people that have given the same reaction

Which is exactly what you're looking for, therefore you can map the collection to get the count property like so:

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(message.id).then(r => {
    return console.log(r.reactions.filter(a => a.emoji.name == '').map(reaction => reaction.count)[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, I'm not sure exactly why, but the `users` prop does not seem to be accurate always. Additionally, `users` is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection), which does not have a `.size` property.

Instead, I'd recommend using the [`<MessageReaction>.count`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=count) property. Like this:

```
message.channel.fetchMessage('<message id>')
.then(msg => {
    let downVoteCollection = msg.reactions.filter(rx => rx.emoji.name == '');

    console.log(downVoteCollection.first().count);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

You can use the `.first()` method of the `Collection` because you'll only get the downvote emojis returned, so there will only ever be one type of `MessageReaction` returned in that collection.